# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{2+(-1)^{n}}}$, diverging or converging?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{2+(-1)^{n}}}$$

Does this series converge or diverge ?
The alternating series test doesn't works as, this series is not monotone nonincreasing. Note that:

$$(n^{2+(-1)^{n}})=(1,2^3,3,4^3,5,6^3,7,8^3,...)$$

How could I prove this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subseries $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{(2n)^3}$ of terms with even indices converges, and the subseries $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{-1}{2n-1}$ of terms with odd indices diverges, so the whole series diverges. The partial sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{2+(-1)^n}}$$

is a sum of partial sums of the two subseries; for large $m$ one of those is close to $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{(2n)^3}$, and the other can be made arbitrarily large in magnitude. That should be enough of a start for you to fill in the $\epsilon$-$n$ details.